# Clarify interrupt mechanism on STM32H7

Tags: exception, stm32

I am a bit confused about the way interrupts are handled on a STM32H7. The confusion is about level-sensitive versus pulse-sensitive interrupts and the documentation from ST is not crystal-clear on the topic.

I want to be sure that the following understanding is correct:

- the STM32 NVIC is configured to handle all interrupts as level-sensitive. This is why an ISR has to clear a bit in a peripheral to deassert the interrupt signal (going from this peripheral to the NVIC). if it doesn't do it, the corresponding interrupt remains in (or goes back to) state Pending after the ISR exits.
- but at peripheral level, for GPIOs, interrupts are pulse-sensitive in the sense that the EXTI peripheral latches either a rising edge or a falling edge (of both) on a GPIO signal. When it detects such an event it asserts its interrupt line that goes to the NVIC. That interrupt line remains asserted until the software clears a dedicated bit in EXTI. But at the same time if the GPIO remains high (say you keep a button pressed), EXTI will not latch another interrupt.

So, as far as GPIOs are concerned, we could say the interrupts are both pulse and level sensitive ?

Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: Where is the contraversion. EXTI is the stm peripheral and detects edges. NVIC just controls and handles the interrupt signals generated by peripherals and core. Y

Comment: I don't say there is a contraversion, I just want to be sure I understood correctly. I've read several times in discussions that STM32 uses only pulse sensitive interrupts, it's somehow confusing.

Comment: As I wrote, you need to understand the difference between EXTI and NVIC.  NVIC levels only show that the the source want to trigger exception or not. External interrupt controller made by STM is something completely different and your thesis does not make too much sense and is wrong.

Comment: What thesis ? A very pleasant answer from you, as usual...

Comment: `the interrupts are both pulse and level sensitive` no, it is not the truth